# How to fix an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following line of code is causing an uncaught TypeError:

```
document.getElementById('leaveblank').className = "noshow";
```

I know this is because there is no #leaveblank ID in the DOM (the script is used on another page). I also know the way to fix this is probably by adding an IF statement.

However, I'm not sure what the syntax should look like for this, or if I need to set the getElement as a var first?

Full console error below for reference:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied by the error you quote, `document.getElementById()` returns `null` if it doesn't find an element for the id you supply. So:

```
var el = document.getElementById('leaveblank');
if (el != null)
    el.className = "noshow";
```

You can simplify the `if` condition to:

```
if (el)
```

...because if an element is found then `el` will be an object and all objects are "truthy".

If you're using jQuery (as implied by how you tagged the question) you don't have to worry about whether the element exists, you can just do:

```
$("#leaveblank").attr("className", "noshow");
// or, if you just want to add the class to the element
$("#leaveblank").addClass("noshow");
```

The `$("#leaveblank")` part creates a jQuery object containing either one or zero elements; jQuery methods like `.attr()` or `.addClass()` operate on whatever elements happen to be in the jQuery object they're called on with no error if there are no elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var lb = document.getElementById('leaveblank');
if(lb)
 lb.className = "noshow";
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery there will be no error because jQuery takes care of this:

```
$('#leaveblank').attr('class', 'noshow');
```

Pure JS would be:

```
if (document.getElementById('leaveblank').length) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Your pure JS solution would give pretty much the same error as the OP's code. `null` doesn't have a `.length` property.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of to check if an element actually exists or not is to check its length property like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('leaveblank').length == 0)
{
    // Element does NOT exist in the DOM
}
```

Comment: That will give the same error that the OP is currently getting, because `null` doesn't have a `.length` property.

Comment: No, I don't believe it will. It will give an object that has zero length.

Comment: No it won't. You're confusing it with how the `$()` jQuery function works. `.getElementById()` returns a reference to a DOM element, or `null` if there's no element with the id in question. (And if an element is found it is unlikely to have a `.length` property, unless it's a select element.)

Comment: Nope, apologies.
I just made a JSFiddle to test my idea and length only works for the jQuery object. I was wrong.
http://jsfiddle.net/RoboBear/krLkT/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should always get the element in a variable and check if it not null and then do further operation on it.